# How can I look up by index within an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my view, I have:

`<div class="grid-wrapper grid-view type-A has-thumbnail" ng-repeat="artist in artists">`

So `artist.id` has an id for that artist.

I have another object called `album_artists` that looks like:

```
album_artists = {
  '1231': {
    ...
  },
  '1232': {
    ...
  }
}
```

So within my `div, I want to get the`album_artists`that corresponds to a particular`artist.id`. How can I do this?

What I want is something like:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper grid-view type-A has-thumbnail" ng-repeat="artist in artists">
  <div class="otherstuff" ng-repeat="album in albums[artist.id]">
```

Is this valid?

Comment: Assuming that the `artist.id` value is a key of the `album_artists` object, you can do the following inside the div: `{{album_artists[artist.id]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do

```
<div class="otherstuff" ng-repeat="album in album_artists[artist.id]">
```

then you have to change your data structure to an array for each value of the key (eg. '1231') like this

```
album_artists = {
    '1231': [{...
    }],
    '1232': [{...
    }]
}
```

If you don't want to change the data structure, you can do

```
<div class="otherstuff" ng-repeat="(key, value) in album_artists[artist.id]">
```